# Will we lost the views and clicks in Admob ads while the app is not linked?

Tags: android, admob

we have a new app published today in Play Store and we use Admob ads in their activities. However, we could not find the app when we tried to link it in the Admob. After looking here (in Stack Overflow) we saw this is because Admob indexing takes approximately 48 hours. In this interval while the app is not linked, will we receive for the views and clicks?
Do they already count or only after the app is linked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will count.

The app linking has no impact upon view or clicks.